# Adding Curly Braces to Map block in nginx

Tags: nginx, regular-expressions

I am having a problem trying to get the following configuration to work. Every time I run the config test I get a failed pass. To start off let me show you a working configuration

> `location / {
>       if ($query_string ~ "mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D)"){
>           return 403;
>       }
>   }`

But when I try be a little clever and place this in a map block I get a error

> `map $query_string $edgars_access_denied {
>       default "200";
>       ~mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) "403";
>   }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Curly braces like semi-colons have a special meaning in nginx's configuration thus you must turn your regex into an explicit string by surrounding it with either single or double quotes.

```
map $query_string $edgars_access_denied {
    default "200";
   "~mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D)" "403";
}
```